# LibreOffice: how to make a Radio Button group

Tags: forms, radio-button, controls, libreoffice, radio-group

**In a LibreOffice Writer document, how do I make a radio button group?**  I cannot get my buttons to "group".

I'm using LibreOffice 5.3.4.2 (x64).

I place multiple Radio buttons controls in my Writer document.

I select two buttons and, in the controls' Properties, I assign them the same Group Name.

I select two other buttons and assign them their own, same Group Name.

*Example*:

> "Do you like dogs? O Yes, O No."  (These would be the "**Dogs**" group)
>
> "Do you hate cats? O Yes, O No."  (These would be the "**Cats**" group)

I export the PDF as a form and open it in Adobe Acrobat.

The buttons are there, but the groups are not separate. The groups are not mutually exclusive and even within a group, the options are not exclusive.

The problem is probably in the naming of the individual buttons or the group but the solution eludes me. Consulting Mr. Google hasn't helped.

Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

Set each radio button in the group to the same NAME.  Leave the GROUP NAME blank.

Then "Export to PDF..." as a form and the buttons will work as expected.

***Speed tip*:**

Quickly select all buttons to be grouped by holding SHIFT while clicking each button. With the group selected, Right-click to display the context menu. Select "CONTROL..." and enter your values in the fields.

Comment: I had trouble getting this working in LibreOffice 6.4.5.2. It turns out I had to export as PDF/A, by clicking "Archive", the other one isn't working (anymore, I think this worked previously?).

Comment: But then it doesn't work on Windows machines or Acrobat reader it seems :'( Why did this stop working. :'(